# Finding the widest angle to shoot a soccer ball from the sideline using optimization!!

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

[image]

I'm trying to do an independent project for my Math class, but I was stuck and couldn't figure out how to use optimization to find position along the sideline that gives the widest angle to shoot. As in the picture, A and C demonstrate positions that provide smaller angle to shoot, while B provides a wider angle to shoot. I tried using law of cosine, but because both sides of triangles change every times I didn't know how to apply optimization to it :(

if anyone know, please help, any suggestion would be appreciate

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiomontanus%27_angle_maximization_problem

Comment: Lest anything be unclear: There is a Wikipedia article about this very problem, and Will Jagy has linked to it.  It has at least two solutions not involving calculus, and one that does.  Note that if you use calculus, it is simpler to maximize the tangent of the angle than to maximize the angle directly.

Comment: also in http://store.doverpublications.com/0486613488.html inexpensive translation of Dorrie.

Comment: This problem, attributed to Regiomonatanus, has a large literature. If you have access to Ivan Niven's Maxima and Minima without Calculus (nice book) there is a good discussion there. There are also efficient calculus solutions.